# Problem with grub Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC and when I restarted the PC it told me that it does not have any Operating Systems installed, ok, so I tried to reinstall grub with the Ubuntu live CD Installing for x86_64-efi platform.grub-install, but I got the following error: `cannot find EFI directory`.

I have only just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my hard disk and I really want to start using it, so can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Ubuntu (or you if you used manual partition) messed up during partitioning and didn't set up a small (512MB) fat32 partition, which EFI needs, if you don't want to re-partition you can simply install plain old MBR and that's it.

Comment: I have an fat32 partition yet with 500MB in gparted have boot and legacy_boot flag,so, any idea what can solve my problem (thanks for an so early reply)

Comment: There's the problem, you don't need a legacy_boot flag, you need to remove that, and do.... well, whatever EFI needs for it's partition, but it sure doesn't need legacy_boot......